# Querybuilder Doctrine groupBy trigger error sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: symfony, doctrine

For an entity "Message" , I need to get for a receiver last messages group by User field.

Here is the entity with its relations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MessageRepository")
 */
class Message
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="messages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $User;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="receivedmessages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $receiver;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $creationdate;
```

So far this is my querybuilder in Message repository to get last message for receiver by User:

```
public function getConversations($dest)
{
  $qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->Where('c.receiver = :dest')
    ->setParameter('dest', $dest)
    ->orderBy('c.creationdate', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('c.User')
  ;

  return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

When I run this query I get error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'spro.m0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

In other treads some say that we need to remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from mysql console to avoid this error, some others say that it is not recommanded.

Is there another way to do my query without having to change database settings ?

EDIT: I tried as well to get Message from repository User instead doing it from Message repository like this:

```
public function getConversations($id)
{
  $qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->andWhere('u.id = :val')
    ->setParameter('val', $id)
    ->Join('u.receivedmessages', 'd')
    ->groupBy('d.User')
    ->Select('d')
  ;

  return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

In this case I get error message:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT d FROM': Error: Cannot
>   select entity through identification variables without choosing at
>   least one root entity alias.